# Express.js Continues to Show 'Not Found' After Removing Default Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I thought this was a caching issue, but after three complete removals of all code on my server, I'm still encountering the same issue:

Express Generator comes with the default error handling in the **app.js** file:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

I have since replaced that code with my own catch all route, using *app.all*:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler (catch-all)
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

**Keep in mind** that the render statement works. I'm using a single page application and I need it to redirect back to the index.html file.

This actually works locally, but does not work on my server. The server is a Node.js server.

The default message for the 404 error is "Not Found". No matter how many times I remove this code and the 404 error message, I continue to see "Not Found" (Express.js style) on my browser, instead of a redirect to my home page.

Comment: Since the issue is with "my server", you could elaborate on it a little more. But anywho, I think in general you have to be assured that the node.js process is being restarted and that you have cleared your server's cache, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question, the issue was with my web host. The server uses Phusion Passenger and the app.js on the Node.js server needed to be restarted.

I needed to create a file in the root of the server called restart.txt inside of a folder named 'tmp':

```
nano tmp/restart.txt
```

Afterwards, if I wanted to manually restart the server, I would have to run the following command:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Which would restart the app.js file.